# Automatically add command line options to setup.py based on target

Tags: python, setup.py

When I run setup.py, I generally want to add different command line options to the call, based on which kind of distribution I'm building.

For example I want to add `--user-access-control force` if I build a windows installer (bdist_wininst).
Another example would be omitting the call to a post-install-script when building a source distribution.

My current solution would be to create small .bat and .sh scripts with the desired call to setup.py, but that feels somehow wrong.
Is there a better way to do what I want, or are my instincts failing me?

**Edit:** Found the correct way. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the "correct" way to do it was pretty straight forward and I just missed it when looking in the documentation:

**Use `setup.cfg`.**
It's a standard config-file, where you can define a section for each build-target / kind of distribution (`sdist`, `bdist_wheel`, `bdist_wininst`, etc.), which contains the command line options you want to give to setup.py when building it.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to detect the OS in the setup.py:

```
import os
print(os.name)

if os.name == 'posix':
    ...
```

Comment: how does that solve my problem? I don't want to do different actions based on OS but give different options to setup.py depending on what kind of distribution I build.